# Change a TensorFlow tensor of shape (128, 10, 51) to a tensor of shape (128, 51) by choosing only one element in 2nd dim of the tensor

Tags: tensorflow, slice, tensor

I want to change a TensorFlow tensor of shape (128, 10, 51) to a tensor of shape (128, 51) by choosing only one element in 2nd dim of the tensor. I have indicies must be choosed in a ndarray, like this:

A is a tensor of shape (128, 10, 51)

B is a ndarray of shape (128,) with elements 0 to 9

I did it by for loop, but i want a compact code to do this in one/two line/s.

Comment: Welcome to SO Behnam. What about this? `result = tf.gather_nd(A, tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(A)[0]), B], axis=1))`.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer I posted below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following line:

```
result = tf.gather_nd(A, tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(A)[0]), B], axis=1))
```

the `tf.gather_nd` function gets slices from tensor A based on indices stored in `tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(A)[0]), B]`.